# When voting close should the comment be considered

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

When in the vote close queue, I never read comments.
But today, on this peculiar question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/246445
I found out that I should have because without comment the question is terrible, but with comment it's starting to make sense.

Should comments be taken into account (not sure if this formulation English it' a good translation of French at least), or should I just ignore them and consider the OP should have edited its question (while here obviously it's a new comer) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a representative sample from the file that the user linked to the text of the actual question.  I should really have done that when I answered it.  Thanks for bringing it up!

I have also voted to reopen the question.

IMHO, comments should be taken into account when reviewing.  In some cases, especially when the close vote is "off-topic: typo", this may only be evident from comments.  If the question is voted as "unclear", and is clarified by comments, then ideally, those comments should be moved into the text of the question.  If the user hasn't done so themselves, a reviewer could well do this.

Comment: OK I'll try to pay more attention to comment next time

Answer (score 1):

Why ignore it? If you see useful information in the comments, just edit them into the original post.

That's what should be done with useful comments in general, anyway.